# My wireless card is not being detected

Tags: wireless-networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, scientific-linux

I have a NIC Realtek rtl8111/8168b with the r8168 drivers in use (note that the r8169 drivers that come with the card do NOT work) with a Scientific Linux with kernel version 2.6.32 that does not detect the NIC. When I put in terminal:

> ifconfig -a

it only appears eth0 and lo but not the wlan0.

At first I thought that the NIC was not correctly plugged in the motherboard but the led power of the NIC is turned on. My motherboard model is a Gigabyte GA-F2A85XM-D3H.

I got the following info:

> lshw -class network
>
> *-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 06
   serial: 94:de:80:b0:8b:cf
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.037.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:26 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0004000-d0004fff(prefetchable) memory:d0000000-d0003fff(prefetchable)
```

> *-network UNCLAIMED

```
   description: Network controller
   product: Ralink corp.
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 6
   bus info: pci@0000:02:06.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm cap_list
   configuration: latency=32 maxlatency=4 mingnt=2
   resources: memory:fea00000-fea0ffff
```

Besides, I also found the following info:

> dmesg | grep eth
>
> eth%d: 0xffffc90000c50000, 94:de:80:b0:8b:cf, IRQ 26

```
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
r8168: eth0: link up
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

All suggestions are welcome to attack this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The Realtek 8111/8168b is your ethernet card, not your wireless card. It is correctly detected  and works fine, as shown by output of lshw and of dmesg (*eth0 is up*).

Your wireless card is not correctly set up, but we cannot know why yet. The reason is we do not know its make and model. All we know is your Operating System does not have a proper driver for it (UNCLAIMED; this is what it means).

In order to make prgress you will have to post the output of

```
  lspci -vnn | grep -i net
```

Comment: Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co.,Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)

Comment: @AlejandroRamos Nope, as you can see that is your Ethernet card. Anything in the output of lspci -vnn about a wifi card, a Ralink thingy?

Comment: It says: Realtek Semiconductor RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller.